# Angular directive not working using Yeoman

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, gruntjs, yeoman

I am trying to test a directive created with the following

```
yo angular:directive countriesDirectives
```

this is the resulting directive with some changes

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name miaplicacionApp.directive:countriesDirective
 * @description
 * # countriesDirective
 */
angular.module('miaplicacionApp')
  .directive('countriesDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<h1>hjbjhbjhbjbjhbjhbjhbjhbjhbjhbjhbjhb</h1>',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attr) {
        element.text('this is the countriesDirective directive');
      }
    };
  });
```

here i am including the directive in my index.html

```
<div class="container cont">
        <h1>jkm</h1>
         <countriesDirective></countriesDirective>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
```

then I run ''grunt serve''. Everything works as i expect but the directive doesnt work. it is worth mentioning that when Yeoman creates the app, it includes all the necessary files for it work. but for some reason my directive is not working.

Comment: Typo? it should be `countries-directive` and not `countriesDirective` when used in the html. Check out [directive normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization).

Answer (score 1):

The HTML tag should be `<countries-directive></countries-directive>`.

Angular translate camelCase to spinal-case.

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake for people who does not use angularjs so much. So, what happened to me while creating `yo angular:directive payment-form` was:

- output after run command: `angular.module('myApp').directive('paymentForm', function () { ... more content...});`
- Inside page.html page I used in this way:
  `<paymentForm></paymentForm>` which is wrong. The right way is: `<payment-form></payment-form>`